# How to display in a View a returned value from a completion handler in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire, completionhandler

I have a class that has these two methods:

```swift
private func send(method: String, path: String, code: Array<Int>, headers: HTTPHeaders, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        let url: String = "\(self.credentials.url)/\(path)"

        AF.request(url, method: HTTPMethod(rawValue: method), headers: headers)
            .authenticate(with: self.request_credentials)
            .response { response in
                let status_code: Int = response.response!.statusCode
                
                completionHandler(status_code as Int)
            }
}
```

And

```swift
func list_files(path: String) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Depth": "1"
        ]
        
        send(method: "PROPFIND", path: path, code: [207, 301], headers: headers) { status_code in
            self.status_code = String(status_code)
        }
}
```

So both of these functions use completion handlers because of the fact that Alamofire uses them in its process of making HTTP requests.
I understood that I have to use completion handlers this way to handle this async data.

My current issue is that now I have to display this data (let's say `self.status_code`) in a view but I have no idea how to do this. When I display it like this :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let auth = Authentication(username: "****",
                                  domain: "****",
                                  password: "****",
                                  port: ****,
                                  proto: "****",
                                  path:"****")
        
        let commands = Commands(credentials: auth.get_credentials())
        
        let _ = commands.list_files(path: "/")
        
        Text(commands.status_code)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

It will display the initialization value of status_code (which is 0) instead of the updated value by list_files method. I know this is because of the asynchronous behavior of these completion handlers and the value is not yet updated when I display it.

But here's the question: how can I manage to properly display this updated value to the user?

I'm probably doing lots of things wrong here and I don't mind receiving a completely different solution since I'm willing to follow the best practices.

Thank you.

Comment: Pass a completionHandler in your method list_files also and show value in UI from this completion.

Comment: That's also something I tried but it seems difficult (or impossible?) to handle completion handler functions inside a View, would you have any example of how I could achieve this? I'll check further though. Thanks.

Comment: 'viewModel.isRefreshing {[weak self](loading) in
    if loading {
        self?.updateUI()
    }
}
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a Playground with a complete example.  I'll walk through some of the important things to note.

First I simplified the "send" method since I don't have all the types and things from your original example.  This send will wait 3 seconds then call the completion handler with whatever message you give it.

Inside the view, when the button is pushed, we call "send".  Then, in the completion handler you'll notice:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    message = msg
}
```

I don't know what thread the `Timer` in send is going to use to call my completion handler.  But UI updates need to happen on the main thread, so the `DispatchQueue.main...` construct will ensure that the UI update (setting `message` to `msg`) will happen on the main thread.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

func send(message: String, completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { timer in
        completionHandler(message)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        print("Building view")
        return VStack {
            TextField("blah", text: $message)
            Button("Push Me", action: {
                send(message: "Message Received") { msg in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        message = msg
                    }
                }
            })
        }.frame(width: 320, height: 480, alignment: .center)
    }
}


let myView = ContentView()
let host = UIHostingController(rootView: myView)
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = host
```

Comment: Thank you. I adapted your example to my code doing this: declared `@State var status_code: String` inside my class and wrapped `self.status_code = String(status_code)` with DispatchQueue.main.async inside the `list_files` method of this class (as shown in my original message). I didn't change anything in the view body. It still displays "0" for the status_code, what did I do wrong?

Comment: It works when I initialize my class as: `@ObservedObject var commands: Commands` and the value I wanna keep track of, inside the class, as: `@Published var status_code: String`. In this case, the View is automatically updated once the status_code value changes (I can see it go from 0 to 207). Is my approach the right one for this specific case with classes? It works but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do or if there is a better way.
Thanks.